# Standard matrix from Projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the standard matrix of the given linear transformation from ${\bf R}^2$ to ${\bf R}^2$

Projection onto the line $y=2x$

So basically, I got the standard matrix to be 
$$
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0 \\
  2 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
  \right),
$$
my question is: is this actually right? I have been looking online and it appears that maybe I am wrong?

Comment: You can always try a simple test case and see if you get the right answer. For instance, if you were to project $(0,1)$ onto the this line, would the correct answer be $(0,0)$ as suggested by your solution?

Comment: Yeah it should be, since 2(0)=0, therfore it would be (0,0)

Comment: I think you are mistaken. The projection of $(0,1)$ onto this line is definitely not $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line has direction vector $v = (1,2)$. The projection of $(x,y) \in {\bf R}$ onto the line is given by 
$$
  proj_v(x,y)
= \left(\frac{(x,y)\cdot v}{v\cdot v}\right) v
= \frac{x + 2y}{5}v.
$$
The standard matrix for this linear map is thus 
$$
  [proj_v(1,0)' \ \ proj_v(0,1)']
= \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  1/5 & 2/5 \\ 
  2/5 & 4/5 \\
  \end{array}
  \right]
= \frac{1}{5}\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 2 \\ 
  2 & 4 \\
  \end{array}
  \right].
$$

Comment: How did the last step work? Why did you do proju(1,0) proju(0,1), is there a reason you used (1,0) and (0,1)?

Comment: The standard matrix of any linear transformation $T$ (w.r.t. to the standard basis) is given by taking $T(1,0)$ as the first column and $T(0,1)$ as the second column.

Comment: How did you find the direction vector of the line?

Comment: Since we are talking about the line $y=2x$, for a "run" of $1$ you need a "rise" of $2$. The vector $(1,2)$ achieves this (notice we could have used $(2,4)$ also, for instance).