# Compute the matrix corresponding to a projection onto line ($t, 5t, 9t)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a line in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, how does one calculate the corresponding projection matrix onto the line? I'm not sure if my approach is correct.

I am given a line $(t, 5t, 9t)$ with $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

I read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741522/standard-matrix-from-projection), but I don't understand how (if) I can use a similar process for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: The projection is a linear transformation, so it suffices to know the images of basis vectors. So calculate the projections of $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ and be done with it.

Comment: That is the approach I took (as the other commenter alluded to). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sketch of a way:*

- Notice that your line is just the subspace vector $W$ of $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ given by $$W:=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbf{R}^{3}: x=t, y=5t, z=9t,t\in \mathbf{R}\right\}={\rm span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 5\\ 9\end{pmatrix} \right\}$$
  Now, you can calculate the projection matrix $P$ over $W$ (i.e., onto the line) as  [$P=A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^{\top}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2707282/1027216).
- Now, about your question notice that the director vector for the line is just $(1,5,9)$ then you can apply that method in the answer that your suggested.